# Renaming multiple files using a Shell Script

Tags: shell, file-rename

I have files named `t1.txt`, `t2.tx`t, `t3.txt` ... `t4.txt` and I need a shell script to rename it like this:

file one:  `M.m.1.1.1.201108290000.ready`

file two:  `M.m.1.1.1.201108290001.ready`

etc, the sequence number in the last 4 digits changes.

I'd be grateful if someone helped me :)

Best Regards

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: With simple knowledge of bash you should be able to do that.

Comment: what I need is Unix 'Linux' shell scrip ,to change file name .

Comment: cd /home/me/Desktop/files/renam/
seq=201108290000
for file in `ls -1`
do
echo $file
prefix=M.m.1.1.1.
file_name=M.m.1.1.1.$seq.ready
echo $file_name
seq=`seq+1`
mv $file $file_name 
done

Comment: What do you have that isn't working? We're happy to entertain any question you may have while stuck on something, but the community tends to frown when questions try to 'place an order'.

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you need:

```
cd /home/me/Desktop/files/renam/
n=201108290000
for file in *.txt; do
    echo $file
    prefix=M.m.1.1.1.
    file_name=M.m.1.1.1.$n.ready
    echo $file_name
    n=$(( $n+1 ))
    mv $file $file_name
done
```

It's close to what you'd written yourself, you just missed some bash syntax. Note that you might want to change the initial value of `n`, otherwise for the files you mentioned `t1.txt` would become `M.m.1.1.1.201108290000.ready`. Depending on what your use is, that might be confusing.

I'd also advice you to avoid use the names of programs and builtins as variable names, such as `seq` in your case.