# unix: renaming batch of files - how do I add numbers from 1 to 4000 to the filenames of 4000 files?

Tags: bash, unix, rename, batch-processing

I have 4000 files, and I need to add the nrs 1 to 4000 at the beginning of all filenames.

For example:

```
file_a.CEL
file_c.CEL
file_g.CEL
file_x.CEL
...
other_file.CEL
```

Should become:

```
1_file_a.CEL
2_file_c.CEL
3_file_g.CEL
4_file_x.CEL
...
4000_other_file.CEL
```

It is important that the underscore after the number also gets added. The filenames are all totally different (there is no system to the filenames), and it also doesn't really matter in what order they are numbered. Is there an easy way to do this using bash? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a`for` loop and `mv` should give you the desired effect. It's not a particularly interesting solution, but it's simple.

```
COUNT=1
for file in ./*; do
    mv "$file" "${COUNT}_$file"
    let COUNT++
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i=1
for f in *; do 
   echo Renaming file \"$f\" to \"${i}_${f}\"
   mv "$f" "${i}_${n}"
   i=$((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Related topic: [Renaming multiple files using a Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231248/renaming-multiple-files-using-a-shell-script)

In your case you could do as follows:

```
n = 1
for file in *.CEL; do
   new_name=$n_$file
   n=$(($n+1))
   mv $file $new_name
done
```